# How to frame my URL to send GraphQL request to the application running inside a container on linux machine from windows machine?

Tags: linux, docker, graphql, containers, citrix

I have a linux machine assigned to me on AWS cloud and I am running my SpringBoot application in a docker container inside **this** linux machine on AWS cloud. To hit this application's graphQL endpoint from my windows laptop what host name or URL should I use? 
and how can I frame it?

In general if this application is running in my local, I will use something like http://localhost:8080/graphQL.

The DockerFile for this application has this command -> EXPOSE 8080.

I am confused because there is a linux machine ip address and also container ip address and I don't know which one to use, so I tried both.

On that linux machine I typed 'ip address' on its terminal and it is throwing me bunch of information and I am not sure which one is my ip address.

To get ip address of container I used below command and it returned me some address. I used it https://172.17.5.3:8080/graphql from my windows laptop but it is not returning the response.

```
    docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}} 
    {{end}}' container_name_or_id
```

Please let me know for any additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The DockerFile for this application has this command -> EXPOSE 8080.

The `EXPOSE` directive doesn't really do anything (in this context). It's informative: it tells you that the container will run a service on port 8080. This will not, by default, be available from outside of your Docker host.

You can expose this port on your Linux machine by "publishing" it when you start the container.  You can do this using the `--publish` (`-p`) option to `docker run`.  For example, if you were to start your container like:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 ...
```

Then you would be be able to access the service on port 8080 of your Linux machine's ip address or hostname, assuming that there aren't firewall rules in place that prevent the connection.

You can read more about Docker port publishing (and networking in general) in [this document](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/).

> On that linux machine I typed 'ip address' on its terminal and it is throwing me bunch of information and I am not sure which one is my ip address.

You would generally use your instance's public ip address. [This document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/using-instance-addressing.html) has information on working with public ip addresses in AWS.